# How to use \DeclarePairedDelimiter commands as moving arguments (such as sections or captions)?

Tags: table-of-contents, mathtools, delimiters, fragile

I am having trouble to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` commands from the mathtools package with the optional size argument inside *moving arguments* such as section titles (or caption texts), when a table of contents (or list of figures) also is to be generated in the document. Consider the following minimal (non-)working example with a `\norm` delimiter:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

% \tableofcontents

\section{This works: $\norm{x}$}
\section{Also works: $\norm*{x}$}
\section{This fails: $\norm[\big]{x}$}

\end{document}
```

Without the `\tableofcontents`, all three sections work and the document compiles correctly. However, with the `\tableofcontents`, the last section causes the compilation to fail:

```
Argument of \\MT_delim_norm_nostar: has an extra }.
Paragraph ended before \\MT_delim_norm_nostar: was complete.
Missing $ inserted.
```

Does anybody have an idea how to properly use the `\norm` command with a specific (`[\big]`, `[\Big]`, etc.) size argument, so compilation does not fail when creating the table of contents? Simply adding `\protect` directly in front of the affected `\norm` commands does not seem to help.

Comment: For some reason, `$\norm[\big]{x}$` is not saved as such in the `.toc` file. If you modify the .toc file with the code in the .tex file, it's O.K. Maybe a bug of the package?

Comment: @Bernard as a test I tried making the internal macro behind `[\big]` robust, but that did not help much

Comment: @daleif: so it might be worth reporting the problem to the authors of mathtools.

Comment: Try this: `\section{This fails: $\big(x\big)$}` it is expanding `\big` before writing it to the toc it seems. `mathtools` treats `\big` as a string and strips the ``\``, in order to make it into a `\bigl` and `\bigr` pair. That fails since it is expanded prematuely

Comment: @Bernard already added and issue on github

Answer (score 8):

It seems `\big` and friends gets expanded when written to say `.toc`. I'm not sure if it is possible to robustify `\big` and friends.

Under normal circumstances one uses `\protect` to help it. But then the normal processing of `\norm[\protect\big]{x}` fails (it seems).

It is probably due to `\norm` wanting to treat the `[...]` argument as a string and need to remove the `\` (in order to convert it into say `\bigl` and `\bigr`). Presumably `\protect\big` then makes this fail.

One solution I found to be working it to use the `etoolbox` package and then use `\protecting` around the entire `\norm[\big]{x}`, that seems to work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox}
 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This works: $\protect\big(x\protect\big)$}
\section{This works: $\norm{x}$}
\section{Also works: $\norm*{x}$}
\section{This works: $\protecting{\norm[\big]{x}}$}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, that seems to do the trick (for now).

Comment: Can also robustify `\norm` to protect its arguments... although parsing the optional argument in expansion-only context may be a nontrivial task.

Comment: @user202729 `\norm` is already defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`

Comment: @daleif No, I mean make it so that it expands to something that protects the argument. Without the optional argument it *could* be e.g. `\def \norm#1{\protecting{\robustnorm{#1}}}`, but with it would be hard to distinguish `\norm{[}` and real optional argument.

Comment: @user202729 I was looking at treating the entire arg as a string and then remove protect if present.

Comment: @UlrichDiez that was just a very fast copy

Comment: @UlrichDiez I'd me amazed how much one can actually edit on a phone on a bus to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can robustify `\big` (and the other akin commands):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\robustify\big

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This works: $\norm{x}$}
\section{Also works: $\norm*{x}$}
\section{This works: $\norm[\big]{x}$}

$\norm[\big]{x}\norm{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the near future, `amsmath` will be modified to have `\big` and friends robust. In the meantime you can apply a temporary fix that will do nothing if the document is typeset when `amsmath` is modified as stated.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%% this is just for checking against the future version
\iffalse
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
\renewcommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\renewcommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
\renewcommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
\makeatother
\fi
%%% end

%%% temporary fix until amsmath does \DeclareRobustCommand{\big}{...}
%%% and friends
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\first#1#2\first{#1}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\first\big\first\bBigg@
  % we need to robustify
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  % \big is really robust
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\endgroup
 \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\expandafter\big\expandafter{\big}%
 \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\expandafter\Big\expandafter{\Big}%
 \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\expandafter\bigg\expandafter{\bigg}%
 \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\expandafter\Bigg\expandafter{\Bigg}%
}
{\endgroup}
%%% end of temporary fix

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\ShowCommand\big

\tableofcontents

\section{This works: $\norm{x}$}
\section{Also works: $\norm*{x}$}
\section{This works: $\norm[\big]{x}$}

$\norm[\big]{x}\norm{x}$

\end{document}
```

The first part from `\iffalse` up to the matching `\fi` is just in order to emulate the next version of `amsmath` and is *not* part of the fix. By changing `\iffalse` to `\iftrue`, you'd get that future version. I added it in order to check that the fix would do nothing at all in that case.

Comment: I was trying to use `\MakeRobust` which did nothing. `\robustify` seems a good solution. Any reason why it isn't by default? That the robustify everything hasn't made it into amsmath yet? (might have mathtools make them robust?)

Comment: @daleif It was possibly not the best design to use `\big` and friends instead of `big` (no backslash). Quite likely `amsmath` will make them robust (actually `\protected`, because `\protect` would not work in that context).

Comment: Enrico, as far as I can see \DeclareRobustCommand works too. @daleif \MakeRobust does not work because it was robust in the kernel and made fragile by amsmath so \MakeRobust still sees the internal part of the kernel version. I just made more or less all remaining amsmath commands robust now, so that should show up in the next -dev release.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach thanks for the update. If `\DeclareRobustCommand` also works I'll rewrite my comment in the `mathtools` manual.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach it does not seem to work if I in egregs example replace `\robustify\big` by `\DeclareRobustCommand\big` I probably misunderstod waht you meant.

Comment: @daleif The problem is in timing: the kernel does `\DeclareRobustCommand{\big}{...}`, but then `amsmath` does `\renewcommend{\Big}{...}`, so a later `\MakeRobust{\Big}` has no effect, because `\MakeRobust` checks whether `\Big•` (with a space in the name, here represented by `•`) exists, and it does.

Comment: @egreg ahh, so I just misunderstood Frank. Thanks.

Comment: @daleif it should work with \DeclareRobustCommand, i.e., repeating the amsmath definition but using that instead of \renewcommand, what doesn't work is a simple \MakeRobust because of the reason outlined by egreg

Comment: @FrankMittelbach ok, was just looking for a solution that does not require copying code definitions. I'll leave the comment in the dev manual for mathtools as it is

Comment: @daleif I added a temporary fix.

Comment: well, ni the June release it is gone because amsmath then has robust commands. Other than that you can simply undefine `\csname big \endcsname` after which `\MakeRobust` no longer thinks that the command is robust. However, I would not advice you to do that because *after* June that would be wrong, so copying the short def from amsmath but using `\DeclareRobustCommand`is the safer approach --- see what I have done in the dev branch.